# Apply greater than to a list

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, functions

How can I apply greater than $>$ to a list?

**Example 1**

```
list={1,4,5,-2}
```

How can I apply $>$ to the list to find all elements of the list greater than 0?

*Desired output*

```
{True,True,True,False}
```

**Example 2**

```
list={-(r/(-d + k r)), -(r/(-d + k r)), 0}
```

How can I apply $>$ to the list to find all elements of the list greater  than or equal to 0 in combination with `Reduce`?

*Desired output*

The same as

```
Reduce[{list[[1]] >= 0, list[[2]] >= 0, list[[3]] >= 0}]
```

which has output

```
(k < 0 && ((d < 0 && (r <= 0 || r > d/k)) || (d == 
    0 && (r < 0 || r > 0)) || (d > 
    0 && (r < d/k || r >= 0)))) || (k == 
0 && ((d < 0 && r <= 0) || (d > 0 && r >= 0))) || (k > 
0 && ((d < 0 && d/k < r <= 0) || (d > 0 && 0 <= r < d/k)))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first question, you can map [`GreaterThan`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GreaterThan.html) over the list of values. If they are numeric, it will evaluate to `True` or `False`.

```
GreaterThan[0] /@ {1, 4, 5, -2}
(* {True, True, True, False} *)
```

If the list is not numeric, it does not evaluate,

```
GreaterThan[0] /@ {-(r/(-d + k r)), -(r/(-d + k r)), 0}
(* {-(r/(-d + k r)) > 0, -(r/(-d + k r)) > 0, False} *)
```

and so you can feed the above directly to `Reduce` after removing the last element because `Reduce[{anything, False}]` returns `False`.

```
Reduce[GreaterThan[0] /@ {-(r/(-d + k r)), -(r/(-d + k r))}]
(* (k < 
    0 && ((d <= 0 && (r < 0 || r > d/k)) || (d > 
        0 && (r < d/k || r > 0)))) || (k == 
    0 && ((d < 0 && r < 0) || (d > 0 && r > 0))) || (k > 
    0 && ((d < 0 && d/k < r < 0) || (d > 0 && 0 < r < d/k))) *)
```

Note

```
Reduce[GreaterEqualThan[0] /@ {-(r/(-d + k r)), -(r/(-d + k r)),0}]
```

solves the second example.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was working for.

Answer (score 4):

```
Positive @ {1, 4, 5, -2} (* or *)
Thread[Greater[{1, 4, 5, -2}, 0]]
```

> {True, True, True, False}

```
FullSimplify @ Reduce[NonNegative /@ {-(r/(-d + k r)), -(r/(-d + k r))}] (* or *)
FullSimplify @ Reduce[Thread[GreaterEqual[{-(r/(-d + k r)), -(r/(-d + k r))}, 0]]]
```

> (k < 0 && ((d == 0 && r != 0) || (d < 0 && k r < d) || (d > 0 && 
>              d < k r))) || (d < 0 && 
>          r <= 0 && (d < k r || k <= 0)) || (d > 0 && 
>          r >= 0 && (d > k r || k <= 0))

**Timings:** `Positive@lst` is faster than `Thread[Greater[lst, 0]]` which, in turn, is faster than `GreaterThan[0]/@lst`:

```
lst = RandomReal[{-1,1},1000000];
(r1 = Positive[lst];)//RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.017

```
(r2 = Thread[Greater[lst, 0]];)//RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.414

```
(r3 = GreaterThan[0]/@lst;)//RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.538

```
r1==r2 ==r3
```

> True

Answer (score 3):

For numeric data, integer arithmetric is very fast:

```
list = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {1000000}];
threshold = 2;
a = Greater[#, threshold] & /@ list; // RepeatedTiming // First
b = Positive[Subtract[list, threshold]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
c = Subtract[1, UnitStep[Subtract[threshold, list]]]; // RepeatedTiming // First

a == b
a == (c /. {0 -> False, 1 -> True})
```

> 0.507
>
> 0.016
>
> 0.00370
>
> True
>
> True

You have to interpret `1` as `True` and `0` as `False`. For example, this works very well with the three argument version of `Pick`.

Answer (score 3):

Most compact method:

```
SetAttributes[Greater, Listable];
{1, 4, 5, -2} > 0
(* {True, True, True, False} *)

SetAttributes[GreaterEqual, Listable]
{-(r/(-d + k r)), -(r/(-d + k r)), 0} >= 0 // Reduce
(* your expected output *)
```