# Constructing constraints from a list

Tags: mathematical-optimization, constraint

I want to use `FindMinimum` to minimize some functional, say

```
f[argList_] = Total[argList^2]
```

Now the variables over which to minimize said functional are given as a list `argList`, for example

```
argList = Table[x[i],{i,1,3}]
```

Now I want to constraint the optimization. As I understand it, the constraints have to be of the form `x[1] < 2 & x[2] < 2 & x[3] < 2`:

```
FindMinimum[{f[argList], x[1] < 2 & x[2] < 2 & x[3] < 2}, argList] .
```

My question now is, how do I automatically construct the constraint from `argList`? Specifically, I want this to work for arbitrary lengths of `argList`.

Comment: You can use the answers in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/172359/34893

Comment: Thanks, that answer solved the problem!